# How would I move a transform so that a child transform is in the position of another transform? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

**Abstraction:**
For example, Transform A is parent of Transform B. The goal is to move Transform A so that the position of Transform B is that of Transform C. However, these all need to work in local space of another parent, since the parent will be moving and rotating

**Actual problem:**
I am currently working on an FPS game and I am attempting to make an aim down sights system. I have a gun transform and a position where the camera should go when aiming as a child of that gun. When I aim, the goal is to move the gun so that the position where the camera should be is where the camera actually is. I don't want to move the camera since it would prove difficult later in development. The problem I've run into is that I can't figure out how to move the gun correctly. The gun also needs to return to its original position afterwards, but I already have that working. I just save the original localPosition in the `Start` of the script and go back to it if you aren't aiming.

**Current hierarchy:**

```
Player
      CameraPositon
          Cameras (Local pos of 0,0,0)
             Main Camera (One being used)
          Guns
             Gun1 (One trying to move)
                Iron Sights (Local pos of 0,0,0)
                   Camera Aim Pos (Reference moving point)
```

I've tried `Vector3 offset = camera.transform.position - adsPos.positon`, and adding that to the gun. This works, but only if I add it to the gun's global positon, and I need to add it to the local position since I have other parents that will be moving. I've fiddled with some `transform.InverseTransformPoint` stuff and using that with the `offset` but it just spins in circles if I rotate the player (due to the positions in the offset being global).

If anyone knows of a good way to do this it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So are you saying you tried something like that and its not working??

```
Vector3 offset = transformA.parent.InverseTransformVector(transformC.position - transformB.position);

transformA.localPosition += offset;
```

Simply calculating the distance/offset from B->C, and adding it to local position of A

Comment: This actually does work! I think my problem was that I was using InverseTransformPoint, not InverseTransformVector. Thanks

Comment: @Indigocoder it gets more complex when you also need to match the orientation ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is way easier than you think, you can do this really easily with Scriptable Objects too, you just create the GunScriptableObject, where you store the firerate, the damage, magazine size, etc, and you add a `Vector3 idlePosition`, `Vector3 aimingPosition`.

[Unity documentation about Scriptable Objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) (if you dont know what it is)

**This would give you way more control**, you would be able to set the idle position of each gun, necessary if you have more than 1 gun, and you have already a setup for the firerate, damage, etc.

Here's how you proceed: 
Once you create a GunScriptableObject, set it up, then jump into play mode and find the right (local) aiming position, then copy it to the Scriptable Object and you are good to go.

On the GunController script you would do:

```
[SerializableField] private float aimSpeed = 10f;
[SerializableField] private GunScriptableObject currentGunScriptableObject;
[SerializableField] private Transform gunTransform;

private void Update() {
   if (aiming)
       gunTransform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(gunTransform.localPosition, currentGunScriptableObject.aimingPosition, Time.deltaTime * aimSpeed);
    else
       gunTransform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(gunTransform.localPosition, currentGunScriptableObject.idlePosition, Time.deltaTime * aimSpeed);
}
```

Here is an example of GunScriptableObject.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Gun", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Gun")]
public class GunScriptableObject: ScriptableObject
{
     [Header("Gun Settings")]
     public float fireRate;
     public float magSize;
     public float damage;

     [Header("Local Target Position")]
     public Vector3 idlePosition;
     public Vector3 aimingPosition;
}
```

Comment: I should’ve put this in the main question, but the reason I’m doing it this way is so I could add different sight attachments and switch between them. While I could add the different aiming and idle positions, I feel like it would be easier to add new attachments if you only needed a transform instead of setting a vector 3

Comment: That is true, but you will need scriptable objects sooner or later, you could also create scriptable objects for the sigths, and each sight has an offset adder (it's still really simple and scalable solution).